# Highlighting only the entire phrase in custom Solr Query builder in Java

Tags: java, solr, solr-query-syntax

I'm trying to let Solr highlight only the entire phrase and not every word of the query. Supposing stopwords aren't a problem, my query phrase is: `"hello darkness my old friend"` and the highlighted result will be: `"<em>hello</em> <em>darkness</em> <em>my</em> <em>old</em> <em>friend</em>. <em>hello</em> there."`. What is the Java code to have this result? `"<em>hello darkness my old friend</em>. hello there."`?

Here is your minimum replicable example:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;

String query = "hello darkness my old friend";
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery(query);
q.setHighlightSimplePre("<em>");
q.setHighlightSimplePost("</em>");
String[] queryArray = query.split(" ");
```

I have already tried with:

```
q.setHighlightFragsize(query.length());
q.set("hl.usePhraseHighlighter", true);
q.set("hl.useFastVectorHighlighter", true);
q.setTermsMinCount(queryArray.length);
q.set("hl.multiTermQuery", true);
```

but with no luck.

Note: for bool values eg. `usePhraseHighlighter` i even tried putting `true` as string. Nothing changed

Thank you everybody in advance

Comment: Note that a _phrase_ query must be surrounded by quotes, the string should be set as `'"hello darkness my old friend"'` so that Solr can parse `"hello darkness my old friend"`.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the unified highlighter in Solr 7 and newer, you can set the `hl.weightMatches` parameter to `true` to get the phrase highlighting exactly how you want. In Solr 8 this option is enabled by default.